# CSS3 hover and active problems

Tags: css, html

Trying to make CSS functional map:

### CSS

```
.fader-us {
    display: none;
}

.fader-us-content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
    z-index:81;
}
    .fader-us:active .fader-us-content {
        display:block;
    }
        .fader-us:active .us {
            opacity:0;
        }

    .fader-us-content:hover {
        display: block;
    }
        .fader-us-content:hover .us {
            opacity:0;
        }

        .fader-us img {
            line-height: 0;
            z-index:79;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
            -moz-transition:    all 0.3s ease;
            -o-transition:      all 0.3s ease;
            -ms-transition:     all 0.3s ease;
            transition:         all 0.3s ease; 
        }

        .us {
            position:fixed;
            top:33px;
            left:55px;
            z-index:0;
        }
```

### HTML

```
        <div class="fader-us">
            <img class ="us" src="us.png" alt="">
            <div class="fader-us-content">
                <li>California</li>
                <li>Florida</li>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What im trying to do is make us.png img to disappear when my mouse is over "fader-us-content".
Can't figure out why is the image disappearing only when I keep clicking.

### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/r9qHa/

Comment: how about providing us with a Fiddle?

Comment: For starters, you can't have list items inside a div like that, they must go into a `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

Comment: @bfavaretto thanks for the note. and what is Fiddle?

Comment: @bfavaretto Awesome! - http://jsfiddle.net/r9qHa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using '~' may be a good way:

```
.fader-us-content:hover~.us {
    opacity:0;
}
```

Change the html like this:

```
<div class="fader-us">
    <div class="text">
        <p>USAs</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="fader-us-content">
        <li>California</li>
        <li>Florida</li>
    </ul>
    <img class ="us" src="http://s23.postimg.org/rixm8ire3/image.png" alt=""/>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/r9qHa/3/)

Comment: worked like a magic! when i left the <img> tag above <div class="text"> it didnt work.. why is that? 
and what does ~ mean?

Comment: ~ means to choice element's next brother element.so <img> needs to be placed behind the <ul class="fader-us-content"> to let ".fader-us-content:hover~.us" work.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
    <div class="fader-us">
        <img class ="us" src="us.png" alt="">
        <div class="fader-us-content">
            <li>California</li>
            <li>Florida</li>
        </div>
    </div>

.fader-us:active .fader-us-content {
        display:block;
    }
```

To This:

```
<div class="fader-us">
        <img class ="us" src="us.png" alt="">
        <div class="fader-us-content">
          <ul>
            <li>California</li>
            <li>Florida</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

.fader-us:active .fader-us-content:hover {
        display:block;
    }
```

Comment: didnt work. im trying to make the img class "us" disappear. what you wrote make "fader-us-content" to disappear when you click on it.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/r9qHa/4/)**</kbd>

Add this rules at tne end of your styles:

```
.fader-us:hover .fader-us-content {
    display:block;
}

.fader-us:hover .us { opacity: 0; }
```